# pinentry not showing in tmux

Tags: x11, tmux, pinentry, yubikey

I'm having some trouble getting `gpg` (actually `pass` which uses `gpg` in the background) to work inside of `tmux` and a Yubikey Neo. When attempting to decrypt a file or sign something using `gpg` I get the following:

```
$ gpg -d test.gpg            
gpg: sending command `SCD PKDECRYPT' to agent failed: ec=5.99
gpg: public key decryption failed: general error
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
```

This is only inside of `tmux`, if I attempt to run the same command in a normal `zsh` session directly in `gnome-terminal` it just works:

```
gpg -d test.gpg 
helloworld
```

`pinentry` will pop up, ask me for the PIN to unlock the Yubikey and proceed to decrypt the file.

I think I narrowed the problem down to `pinentry` not being able to spawn.  Setting the log level of the `gpg-agent` I get the following:

```
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_6 <- INQUIRE NEEDPIN ||Please enter the PIN
gpg-agent[906]: starting a new PIN Entry
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 <- OK Pleased to meet you, process 906
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: connection to PIN entry established
... options removed ...
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 -> GETINFO pid
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 <- D 13381
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 <- OK
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 -> SETKEYINFO --clear
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 <- OK
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 -> SETDESC Please enter the PIN
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 <- OK
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 -> SETPROMPT PIN
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 <- OK
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 -> [[Confidential data not shown]]
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 <- [[Confidential data not shown]]
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: error calling pinentry: Operation cancelled <Pinentry>
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_7 -> BYE
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_6 -> CAN
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_6 <- ERR 100663573 IPC call has been cancelled <SCD>
gpg-agent[906]: DBG: chan_5 -> ERR 83886179 Operation cancelled <Pinentry>
```

Nothing suspicious jumps out at me, except a few `OPTION` statements that apparently aren't handled by `pinentry` but I get the same when calling from `gnome-terminal`.

Setting the `$DISPLAY` variable also doesn't help, the error is identical.

Am I missing something? Is there some other variable I need to set? And why doesn't this fall back to `pinentry-ncurses` if it can't open a graphical one?

Comment: Does `gpg-connect-agent UPDATESTARTUPTTY /bye` help?

Comment: Sadly no change, it replies with `OK` but subsequent calls to `gpg` will error out like previously. I also tried setting the `tty` manually with `export GPG_TTY="$(tty)"` without any change.

Comment: You could trace the running `gpg-agent` with `strace -f -o dump.strace -p $PID` once for both terminals each and then have a look at the differences.

Comment: That's a really good tip, thanks Hauke. I was able to trace both processes side by side and they differ when attempting to talk to `dbus`. The `tmux` `gpg` fails to connect for some reason. If I set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable in `tmux`as well it suddenly works.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to be fixed by adding `set-option -g update-environment 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'` to my `.tmux.conf`. So in the end it was just a stale dbus environment variable...  Thanks for the help Hauke, if you'd like to write a short response I'll gladly accept it ^^

Comment: Make that an answer (and accept it tomorrow) so that this question does not seem unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that (for some reason) `gpg` tries to use dbus but within `tmux` the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` was outdated.

This can be fixed with

```
set-option -g update-environment 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'
```

in `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this didn't work for me by just executing `:set-option ...` from my existing tmux session -- I had to add this to my `.tmux.conf` file and restart tmux (like you say)